# Get all elements of the document except the one with the id 'main-nav'

Tags: javascript

I want to make a hamburger menu from the side, when opened the background should be blurred and hover effects should be disabled. How can i get all elements in the body whitout the one with the id main-nav. I need to get it with javascript without a library like jquery or so.
This is what I thought it should be but it isn't working:

```
document.querySelector('*:not(#main-nav)')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are selecting more than one node you should use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*:not(#main-nav)');
```

Comment: Didn't you notice there was an identical answer before yours ?

Comment: Posted at the same time :)

Comment: This works better but there is a little problem. I forgot to say that in the id main-nav, the ul, li and a tags in this id should also be excluded. Is this posible?

Answer (score 2):

To select more than one element use `querySelectorAll`, not `querySelector`:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('*:not(#main-nav)')
```

But it's unlikely you really need all those elements. There's probably a class or another property you can use to refine your selection and avoid the `*`.

Maybe you just want to select the containers.

My usual solution is to display a div over the elements to blur (probably the whole window) and use the `backdrop-filter` CSS filter with a fallback just opacifying the background for browsers not supporting it.